# Vim formatted print date to current file

Tags: bash, shell, vim, neovim

I am trying to print the current formatted as Mon, 1 Jan 2022 into my current file in vim. So far I've tried the following command, but the `%` sign gets put into the command as the current file.

```bash
:0r !date '+%a, %d %b %Y'
```

This ends up giving me  an output similar to seen below.

```
/home/user/file.txta, /home/user/file.txtd /home/user/fileb /home/user/fileY
```

The issue is that the path to the current file is put in place for `%` as vim does, but that is causing issues for the current use case.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Add backslashes before the `%`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8104

Answer (score 4):

The immediate solution is obviously to escape the `%`:

```
:0r !date '+\%a, \%d \%b \%Y'
```

But you might be interested by the built-in `:help strftime()`, which doesn't require escaping:

```
:0put=strftime('%a, %d %b %Y')
```